# Unable to connect VPN client to OpenVPN server running Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, tun

im a bit new to Linux and also rather stuck with this... any help here would be much appreciated...

I am running Ubuntu 16.0.4 on my server and trying to connect a client to it but no luck. The client is not a device with a video connection or any way to connect to it at the same time that it is trying to establish the VPN connection. I have had the same device recently connected to OpenVPN configured the same way.

I had some trouble with TUN related error messages before running the server setup so I am suspicious that it may be related to this. Its also possibly a routing thing.

Appreciated...

Here is the openVPN log:
Here is the ifconfig of the tun device:
The OpenVPN service starts just fine. Here is the systemctl status:

[OpenVPN log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5D21.png)
[systemctl status log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnFXl.png)
[ifconfig of TUN device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIBI9.png)
[routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlLkn.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it...

The problem was the install script I used. The one that worked in the end was:

wget https://git.io/vpn1604 -O openvpn.sh

It didn't need any changes whatsoever. It setup the TUN and just worked first time.